# The 'tel' link is not working with span style

Tags: html, css

I have a web page where i have a button. I need to automatically dial a phone number on the click of the button. It needs to be done in HTML.  I need to do it on the onclick event of the button

the following code is actually not working when i opened my website on cellphone. The backend is done in php .kindly help

```html
  <a href="tel:+123456789" style="text-decoration:none; color:#1d1d1d;">+123456789</a><br>
     <span>m: <a href="tel:+123456789" style="text-decoration:none; color:#1d1d1d;">+123456789</a>
             </span>
```

On tapping the link it should direct me to call and dial the number automatically.